# Connected component doesn't re-render after store changed from another connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a problem related to redux.
I have 2 connected components which are:

1. avatar situated in the navbar which is always visible
2. profile which is responsible for changing the avatar image in the store

if I am right, when the store change, any connected component will re-render if needed.

In my case, when the action UPDATE_CURRENT_USER update the avatar image, the navbar avatar doesn't get the new image only after I change route or reload page.

I found a solution but many people say it's a hack,
I have put a listener on store changes in the main component and did `forceUpdate()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    store.subscribe(res => this.forceUpdate());
  }
```

and I don't want to use it since connected components are supposed to re-render on store changes.

user actions:

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => dispatch => {
  axios.get("user").then(user => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CURRENT_USER,
      payload: user.data
    });
  });
};

export const updateCurrentUser = user => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: user
  })
}
```

user reducer

```
const initialState = {
    user: {}
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_CURRENT_USER:
            return { ...state, user: action.payload };
        case UPDATE_CURRENT_USER:
            return { ...state, user: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

profile component

```
class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    const { currentUser, updateCurrentUser } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="profile-container">
        <ProfileSider
          currentUser={currentUser}
          updateCurrentUser={updateCurrentUser}
        />
        <ProfileContent
          currentUser={currentUser}
          updateCurrentUser={updateCurrentUser}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: state.userReducer.user
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateCurrentUser }
)(Profile);
```

profile sidebar child of profile

```
class ProfileSider extends Component {
  state = { uploading: false };

  triggerAvatarInput() {
    $("#avatarInput").click();
  }

  handleChange = async event => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, uploading: true });
    const avatarFormData = new FormData();
    avatarFormData.append("file", event.target.files[0]);
    axios
      .post("uploadFile", avatarFormData)
      .then(res => {
        const avatarURIFormData = new FormData();
        avatarURIFormData.append("avatar", res.data.fileDownloadUri);
        axios
          .put("user/update", avatarURIFormData)
          .then(res => {
            const { currentUser } = this.props;
            currentUser.avatar = res.data.avatar;
            this.props.updateCurrentUser(currentUser);
            this.setState({
              ...this.state,
              uploading: false,
              avatar: currentUser.avatar
            });
            message.success("Avatar updated successfully", 3);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, uploading: false });
            message.error("Updating avatar failed!", 3);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, uploading: false });
        message.error("Uploading avatar failed!", 3);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { uploading } = this.state;
    const { currentUser } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="profile-sider">
        <div id="profile-sider-info">
          <div id="profile-sider-info-avatar">
            <div className="container">
              <div
                className="overlay-uploading"
                className={
                  uploading ? "overlay-uploading" : "overlay-uploading hidden"
                }
              >
                <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 50, color: "#FFF" }} />
              </div>
              <div className="overlay" />
              <div className="overlay-text" onClick={this.triggerAvatarInput}>
                <Icon type="camera" style={{ fontSize: 20 }} />
                <span>Update</span>
              </div>

              <div
                className="avatar"
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: "url(" + currentUser.avatar + ")"
                }}
              ></div>
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="file"
                accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
                id="avatarInput"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 style={{ marginTop: 20, textAlign: "center" }}>
            {currentUser.fullName}
          </h2>
          <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{currentUser.email}</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="profile-sider-actions">
          <div className="profile-sider-actions-item">
            <Link to="/profile/courses" style={{ transition: 0 }}>
              <Button type="primary" id="courses-btn">
                <Icon type="read" style={{ marginRight: 15 }} />
                My Courses
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="profile-sider-actions-item">
            <Link to="/profile/update">
              <Button type="primary" id="update-infos-btn">
                <Icon type="sync" style={{ marginRight: 15 }} />
                Update Infos
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfileSider;
```

avatar component situated in navbar

```
class ProfileAvatar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      showProfileDropdown: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentUser();
  }

  handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.logout();
      this.props.onLogout();
      notification["success"]({
        message: "You have been successfully logged out!"
      });
    } catch (ex) {}
  };

  handleClick() {
    if (!this.state.showProfileDropdown) {
      // attach/remove event handler
      document.addEventListener("click", this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showProfileDropdown: !prevState.showProfileDropdown
    }));
  }

  handleOutsideClick(e) {
    // ignore clicks on the component itself
    if (this.element && this.element.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }

    this.handleClick();
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className="profile-avatar"
        ref={element => {
          this.element = element;
        }}
      >
        <Avatar
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          size="large"
          style={{ color: "#f56a00", backgroundColor: "#fde3cf" }}
          src={currentUser.avatar}
        >
          {currentUser.fullName ? currentUser.fullName.charAt(0) : null}
        </Avatar>
        {this.state.showProfileDropdown && (
          <div className="profile-dropdown-list">
            <List
              className="dropdown_list dropdown-shadow "
              size="small"
              style={{ width: "150px" }}
              bordered
              itemLayout="vertical"
              dataSource={[
                <Link to="/profile/update" className="profile-list-item">
                  <List.Item className="list-item">
                    <Icon className="profile-icons" type="user" /> My Profile
                  </List.Item>
                </Link>,
                <Link to="/profile/courses" className="profile-list-item">
                  <List.Item className="list-item">
                    <Icon className="profile-icons" type="container" /> My
                    Courses
                  </List.Item>
                </Link>,
                <List.Item className="list-item">
                  <Icon className="profile-icons" type="question-circle" /> Ask
                  for Help
                </List.Item>,
                <List.Item className="list-item" onClick={this.handleLogout}>
                  <Icon className="profile-icons" type="logout" /> Log out
                </List.Item>
              ]}
              renderItem={item => item}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: state.userReducer.user
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getCurrentUser }
)(ProfileAvatar);
```

image: https://imge.to/i/vywTNj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You are mutating the existing object from the store
- You are sending that exact same user object back into the store when you dispatch the action.

Specifically, these lines are the cause:

```js
            const { currentUser } = this.props;
            currentUser.avatar = res.data.avatar;
            this.props.updateCurrentUser(currentUser);
```

`currentUser` is the user object that's already in the Redux store.  This code mutates the object, and inserts it back into the store.

That results in the connected component thinking nothing has actually changed.

The shortest way to fix this is to create a new user object, and insert that:

```js
const {currentUser} = this.props;
const updatedUser = {...currentUser, avatar: res.data.avatar};
this.props.updateCurrentUser(updatedUser);
```

To avoid this in the future, I strongly encourage you to use [the `configureStore` function from our Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/configureStore), which detects mutations and will throw errors if you mutate.